# Get type parameters as string at run time (Scala 2.11)

Tags: scala

I've been looking at the docs on TypeTag and its ilk but have not been able to solve this.

Is there a way to interpret the parameterized type T at run time in the example below, by replacing ??? with some Scala magic so when run it prints 'SomeClass'?

```
class SomeClass

trait TheTrait[T] {
    def showClassNameOfT = println("class name of T is: " + ???)
}

object Foo extends TheTrait[SomeClass] {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        showClassNameOfT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an implicit `ClassTag[T]` parameter to your method:

```
trait TheTrait[T] {
  def showClassNameOfT(implicit ct:ClassTag[T]) =
    println("class name of T is: " + ct.runtimeClass.getSimpleName)
}
```

Comment: Fabulous!  Thank you so much.